# Replaced pressure balancing unit in Kohler Rite-Temp temperature control, now valve body is leaking

Tags: plumbing, shower, faucet, plumbing-fixture

I have a Kohler Rite-Temp temperature control for my shower that was having trouble regulating hot and cold (it was either all hot or all cold). I took it apart and replaced the pressure balancing unit per the instructions that came with the replacement (roughly like here, but with replacement instead of cleaning: http://helptopics.us.kohler.com/link/portal/5641/5712/Article/2303/K-305-Rite-Temp-Valve-Cleaning).

The problem is that when I put everything back together, I noticed there was some water running out from under the controller when I turned the shower off. I took it apart again and ran it with the cover off. When I turn the dial to the off position, a large amount of water appears to be flowing from the valve body for about 15 seconds. In the picture below, the water appears to come out of the bottom where the little hole is as well as the two screws on either side.

[image: controller]

Is this normal and I've just never noticed because the covers were on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked to make sure the O-rings are seated properly? Also, I had better luck when I replaced the mixing cap and the PBU together. Kohler offers lifetime replacement on these parts, so if you can wait you can save some $$$.

Comment: Yep - went back out and bought a new mixing cap. Once I replaced that along with the PBU, the whole thing worked much better and no more leaking.